# WSO2 API Manager 4.2.0 - How to modify or remove consent purposes - with existing users

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

**Problem**

There is no documentation about how to manage (modify/delete) consent purposes for API manager developer portal self registration form. There is documentation to add consent purposes, but not how to change/delete.

If we try to delete a consent purpose we encounter error `Error while deleting purpose. Purpose is associated with one or more receipt(s).`

**Background**

We are using WSO2 API Manager 4.2.0 with Resident key manager (not WSO2-IS).

We have followed API-M 4.2.0 documentation to customize the developer registration page to define consent purposes for PII information.
[API-M 4.2.0 Customizing User Signup in Developer Portal - adding-consent-purposes](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/customizing-user-signup-in-developer-portal/#adding-consent-purposes)

We have defined two consent purposes:

1. Consent purpose 1 - PII categories:  Given Name, Last Name, Email
2. Consent purpose 2 - PII categories:  Organization, Telephone

We now have a requirement to modify the registration procedure to remove the mandatory Telephone field for future registration requests.

We would therefore like to:

1. Remove Telephone claim from registration form (Claims >> http://wso2.org/claims >> Telephone, set 'Supported by Default' to false, 'Required' to false.)
2. Modify the consent purposes to remove the consent purpose 2 that contained Telephone
3. For simplicity, we would like to modify (or delete and recreate) the remaining consent purpose so that it contains all four remaining mandatory PII fields (Given Name, Last Name, Email, Organization).

**Question**

How can existing consent purposes be managed (remove old consent purposes, amend consent purposes associated with self sign up form, etc) when existing users have already registered using previous consent purposes?

**Testing**

We can add a new consent purpose containing the four claims (Name, Surname, Email, Organization).

We have tried to delete existing consent purpose from 'Consent Purposes >> Actions >> Delete'
This throws an (understandable error):   `Error while deleting purpose. Purpose is associated with one or more receipt(s).`

Tried deleting via Identity Provider. 'Resident Identity Provider >> User Onboarding >> Self Registration >> Manage Self-Sign-Up purposes'
`Error while deleting purpose. Purpose is associated with one or more receipt(s).`

**Research**

We have reviewed existing questions relating to management of consent purposes. For example [unable-to-delete-consent-purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401142/unable-to-delete-consent-purposes). However, this question only relates to if users had been deleted (directly from db) so not entirely relevant.